# LuaLaTex Font Index File Not Writable

Tags: fonts, luatex

I just installed TeXLive 2017 on a new Windows 10 machine. In trying to get LuaLaTeX to process a simple "Hello World" document, I get the following message:

```
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.
luaotfload | db : Failed to save database to disk: nil(save: C:/texlive/2017/tex
mf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.lua)(save: C:/texlive/20
17/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc))
```

The output window also displays

```
lualatex> luaotfload | db : Index file not writeable
lualatex> luaotfload | db : Failed to write to C:/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.lua.
lualatex> luaotfload | db : Failed to write to C:/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.
```

This is the version of LuaLaTeX that I'm running:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX)  (format=lualatex 2018.1.23)  24 JAN 2018 10:02
restricted system commands enabled.
```

I've given myself "Full control" of the `C:/texlive` directory (Read, Write, Modify, etc.).

Is there anything I can do to keep LuaLaTeX from generating a new database each run?

Comment: Review the permissions, and ensure that "full control" applies to the system, yourself as administrator, and possible yourself as ordinary user. If you've already done that... I have no other suggestion. My own Windows 10 partition (migrated from 8) has texlive2017 installed in portable fashion, in my home directory. No problems.

Comment: Do you have some protection software which could interfere? Can you copy/create a file in this directory?

Comment: @RobtAll I thought I had reviewed the permissions properly, but I assumed that permissions would be granted to subdirectories. There is an option to extend them, but that generated Windows errors. So I granted permissions to that specific directory and all works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was due to a Windows 10 Permissions issue. While I actively gave myself and all users "Full Control" to the `C:/texlive` directory, it turns out that those permissions were not automatically extended to subdirectories. I had to specifically give "Full Control" to the `C:/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache` directory.

On the first run, `lualatex` was able to write to the directory it wanted and now the database is created.

Answer (score 0):

If you find this problem on macos. Try rebuilding the database using sudo.

sudo luaotfload-tool --update

This fixed the issue of the database trying to rebuild on every tex compile.